# NZLoad using Pipe File Syntax Issue

Tags: windows, unix, ssis, named-pipes, netezza

I am looking to bulk load some big data from large text files into a Netezza table and was looking at using the named-pipe option. However, I am having some trouble getting it started. To test I am using my windows 64-bit machine and I am calling nzload from an SSIS script task and passing the arguments in. Following an online guide I saved a file as loadme.bat . Can you tell me if the syntax is correct in the file? Or am I way off base and you actually can't do all of the work in the control file? When I tried running this I get an error stating there was a syntax error and it expected a datafile or mkfifo: '<'.

in the .bat file:

```
mkfifo: mkfifo pipefile
cat C:\Testing\DEV\Rawfiles\Testfile.txt > pipefile
nzload -host nzdev -u user -pw pwd -db nzdw -delim "\n" -df pipefile
Datafile loadme.dat
{
Database ebidw
TableName LD_Test_Table.
}
```

Calling it from ssis, this is the argument line I'm using:

```
-host nzdev -u user -pw pwd -cf LoadMe.bat
```

Any help would be appreciated. I can get the table to load fine without using a pipe-file so it's not a driver issue or anything I don't think. I figured I either wrote something incorrectly in the .bat file or my approach just isn't correct and i misinterpreted the guide I read.

Comment: I assume you've installed some additional package that makes mkfifo available on Windows?

Comment: Is the text that is in your first text box *exactly* what is inside of a batch file named "loadme.Bat"?  ...because your control file segement mentinons "Dadtafile loadme.Dat"?